# Best way to do an RxJava call based on the results of the previous API call

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm doing an API call to get the descriptions of a program podcast and based on the type of podcast, I may or may not have to do another API call to get more information.  I'm new to RxJava and I'm not sure the best way to make such calls.  Here's what I have so far:

```
public void fetchFeaturedItems() {
    Timber.i("Fetching Featured...");
    disposables.add(episodeService.getFeatured()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .doOnNext(featured -> { //make second call
            final Episode episode = featured.getEpisode();
            Observable<Timing> timingObservable = episodeService.getTimingForEpisodeActs(episode);
            if (timingObservable != null) {
                timingObservable
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnError(Timber::e)
                    .subscribe(timing -> {episodeManager.saveTiming(timing);}); //save to database

            }

        })
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(featured -> {
            saveFeatured(featured);
            final Episode episode = featured.getEpisode();
            notificationManager.handleNewEpisodeNotification(episode);
        }, Timber::e));
}
```

This all works, but I'm getting a "result of subscribe is not used" lint warning on the second subscribe.  I'm not combining results of the two calls.  I could really use some guidance.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependent-sub-flows

Comment: Ideally the podcast item would have a type property that tells you whether the second call is necessary. It also looks like you should be working with Single<T> and Completable instead of Observable for these calls.

Comment: @Vesper yes it does.  And I have to go with Observable as this is a retrofit call.

Comment: (GET)Single and (PUT/POST)Completable are usually preferable to Observable for retrofit calls in my experience. Especially when chaining calls. You could combine them into an observable if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Use flatMap() instead of onNext(). You get warning about "result of subscribe is not used" cause of second subscribtion. flatMap() should help.

[read this](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) first and other RxJava documentation

Answer (score 0):

`.doOnNext` is a side-effect operator. What you're doing:

```
           timingObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnError(Timber::e)
                .subscribe(timing -> {episodeManager.saveTiming(timing);});
```

Will just create a disposable. This disposable won't be a part of the stream. Also note that the `timingObservable` stream will now run totally independently, because as I just said, `doOnNext` is a side-effect operator. What you're doing is a fire-and-forget call. To make the response as a part of the stream, use a .`flatMap` in place of .`doOnNext`. It will merge your responses as they come, and push them to the downstream operators.

Ideally, a reactive stream should be subscribed to only once - you are doing it twice. This is an immediate code smell.